# Zend Form captcha not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, captcha

I am using following code to create a captcha on a contact form. The code works fine on one my hosting but since I moved my site to 1and1.co.uk the captcha has stopped working.

```
 <?php

    $captcha = $this->createElement('captcha', 'captcha',
                        array('required' => true,
                                'captcha' => array('captcha' => 'Image',
                                        'font' => 'captcha/fonts/arial.ttf',
                                        'fontSize' => '24',
                                        'wordLen' => 5,
                                        'height' => '50',
                                        'width' => '150',
                                        'imgDir' => 'captcha',
                                        'imgUrl' => Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl().'/captcha',
                                        'dotNoiseLevel' => 50,
                                        'lineNoiseLevel' => 5)));
                $captcha->setLabel('* Are you a human? :'); 

   $this->getElement('captcha')->removeDecorator("viewhelper");

 ?>
```

The path and permissions on all the directories used by captcha are valid. I don't understand what's causing the problem as there is no error or exception thrown also all other fields in the form work fine.

One thing I would mention here is that 1and1 is worst hosting anyone could get but I have no option to host it else where as my client wants the site on this hosting....I think suspect that this can be an issue with 1and1 as well...

Comment: Have you checked the path of image and font ??

Comment: Yes! as mentioned in the question.

Comment: "..stopped working" in what way? All entries validate? Or no entries validate?

Comment: i have checked there is no validation issue  i think

Comment: All other fields validate captcha doesn't...